# Is there a hard definition of how CQRS should be applied and CQRS questions

Tags: cqrs

I have some trouble understanding what the CQRS pattern really is, on its core, meaning what are the red lines that, when crossed, we are not implementing the CQRS pattern.

I clearly understand the CQS pattern.

Suppose that we implement microservices with CQRS, without event sourcing.

1) First question is, does the CQRS pattern only apply to the client I/O? Meaning, hoping I get this right, that for example the client updates using controllers that write to database A, but read by querying controllers that write to database B, (B is eventually updated and may be aggregating information from multiple models using events sent by controller of A).

Or, this is not about the client, but anything, for example another microservice reading / writing? And if the latter, what is really the borderline that defines who is the reader / writer that causes the segregation?
Does this maybe have to do with the domains in DDD?

This is an important question in my mind, because without it, CQRS is just an interdependence, of model B being updated by model A, but not the reverse. And why wouldn't this be propagated from a model B to a model C for example?

I have also read articles stating that some people implement CQRS by having one Command Service and one Query Service, which even more complicates this.

2) Similar to the first question, why do some references speak of events as if they are the Commands of CQRS? This complicates CQRS in my mind, because, technically, with one request event we can ask a service "Hey please give me the information X" and the service can respond with an event that contains the payload, effectively doing a query. Is this a hard rule, or just an example to state that, we can update using events and we can query using REST?

3) What if, in most cases I write to model A, and I read from model B, but in some cases I read directly from model A?
Am I breaking CQRS?
What if my querying needs are very simple, should I duplicate model A in this situation?

4) What if, as stated in question 1), I read from model A to emit events, to produce model B, but then I like to read some information from model B because it's valuable because it is aggregated, in order to produce model C?
Am I breaking CQRS?
What is the controller that populates model B doing in that case, e.g. if it also emits events to populate model C? Is it simply a Command anyway because it is not the part that queries, so we still apply CQRS?

Additionally, what if, we read from model A to emit events, to produce model B, but while we produce model B, we emit events, to send client notifications. Is that still CQRS?

5) When is CQRS broken?
If I have a controller that reads from model B, but also emits a message that updates model A, is that it?

Finally, if that controller, e.g. a REST controller, reads from model B and simultaneously emits a message to update model A, but without containing any information from what was read from model B, (so the operation is two in one, but it does not use information from B to update A), is that still CQRS?

And, what if a REST controller, that updates model A, also returns some information to the client, that has been read from A, does that break CQRS? What if this is just an id? And what if the id is not read from A, but it is just a reference number that is randomly generated? Is there a problem in that case because the REST controller updates, but also returns something to the user?

I will really appreciate your patience for replying as it can be seen that I'm still quite confused and that I'm in the process of learning!

Comment: I'm missing a question of what I thought was a yes: Can one controller both read from and write to model A? I assume yes, because how else could we implement X = X + 1, but this would be a Command if I am correct

Comment: Hi, this is way too broad. You should ask only one question per post. Please see [ask] for details.

Comment: Simply imagine that you have two physical machines (each with its own DB) - first one allowed only to accept commands, second one - only answer queries. Machines can talk to each other, but cannot share a database. In event sourced systems first machine sends events to a second one.

Comment: Thanks @RomanEremin! So are these machines two per microservice (or per domain)? Is it strictly forbidden to query from the database of machine A? So, e.g. I can't do: call http://command/message/insert and get back e.g. the message count

Comment: @tkiwi Per domain or per microservice - it is your choice. "S" in cqrS just means that "read side" and "write side" - two completely separate pieces of code, even with different domain model - one is optimized for business logic/commands, and other - for data presentation. They can even be implemented in different languages. I'm familiar with event sourcing flavor of CQRS only. There both sides consumes events (source of truth) and compute their models from these events (usually there is no need to talk to each other)

Comment: @RomanEremin Thanks! I appreciate your time! It makes it a bit clearer to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a hard definition of how CQRS should be applied and CQRS questions

Yes, start with [Greg Young](https://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf).

> CQRS is simply the creation of two objects where there was previously only one. The separation occurs based upon whether the methods are a command or a query (the same definition that is used by Meyer in Command and Query Separation, a command is any method that mutates state and a query is any method that returns a value). -- [Greg Young 2010](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/)

It's "just a pattern", born of the fact that data representations which are effective for queries are frequently not the patterns that are effective for tracking change.  For example, using an RDBMS for storing business data may be our best choice for maintaining data integrity, but for certain kinds of queries we might want to use a replicate of that data in a graph database.

> why do some references speak of events as if they are the Commands of CQRS

`HandleEvent` is a command.  `CommandReceived` is an event.  It's very easy for readers (and authors!) to confuse the contexts that are being described.  They are all "just" messages, the semantics of one or the other really depend on the direction the message is traveling relative to the authority for the information in the message.

For example, if I fill out a form on an e-commerce site and submit; is the corresponding message an `OrderSubmitted` event? or is it a `PlaceOrder` command?  Either spelling could be the correct one, depending on how you choose to model the ordering process.

> What if, in most cases I write to model A, and I read from model B, but in some cases I read directly from model A? Am I breaking CQRS?

The CQRS police are not going to come after you if you read from write models.  In many architectures, the business logic is executed in a stateless component, and will depend on reading the "current" state from some storage appliance -- in other words, to support write often requires a read.

Pessimizing a write model to support read use cases is the thing we are trying to avoid.

Also: horses for courses.  It's entirely appropriate to restrict the use of CQRS to those cases where you can profit from it.  When GET/PUT semantics of a single model work, you should prefer them to separate models for reads and writes.